# To generate all possible combinations of items in a list and STORE them in different lists, and to access them later. I have stated an example below

Tags: python-3.x

```
# To generate possible combinations
from itertools import combinations
main_list=('a1','a2','a3','a4')
abc=combinations(main_list,3)
for i in list(abc):
     print(i)

# Creating number of empty lists
n=6
obj={}
for i in range(n):
     obj['set'+str(i)]=()

# I want to combine these, take list1 generated by combinations and store them down in set1.
```

/* To generate all possible combinations of items in a list and STORE them in different lists. Eg: main_list=('a1','a2','a3'), now i want to combination lists like set1=('a1'), set2=('a2'), set3=('a3'), set4=('a1','a2'), set5=('a1','a3'), set6=('a2','a3'), set7=('a1','a2','a3'). How to access lists set1, set2,... */

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to generate the *power set* - the set of all subsets of the list. Python's [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) package provides a nice example function to generate this:

```py
from itertools import chain, combinations
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))
```

Answer (score 0):

While Nathan answers helps with first part of the question, my code will help you making a `dictionary`, so you can access the sets like `sets['set1']` as asked.

```
from itertools import chain, combinations
def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> () (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))

def make_dict(comb):
    sets = {}
    for i, set in enumerate(comb):
        sets['set'+str(i)] = set
    return sets


if __name__ == '__main__':
    sets = make_dict(powerset(['a1','a2','a3','a4']))
    print(sets['set1'])
```

**Output**

> ('a1',)